Cast the input data from the user (string base type), into an integer
I have an assignment where I need to cast the input data from the user (string base type), into an integer. I am getting the value error when I do this. Where am I going wrong?
raw_inp=input("enter numerical data")
user_inp=int(raw_inp)
if 1<=user_inp<=100:
    print("Congratulations")
else:
    print("Please enter the value again")


The code should work as long as you enter integer as input.

yeah but why not when I enter string? I am casting it right? so it should work with strings as well @PavanChandaka

i did not understand you well , but i tried to add something to your code,
you can try this,

raw_inp = input("enter numerical data :")


if raw_inp.isdigit():
    user_inp=int(raw_inp)
elif ("".join(raw_inp.split("."))).isdigit():
    user_inp=float(raw_inp)
else:
    print("Please enter a valid data")
    exit()



if 1<= user_inp <=100:
    print("Congratulations")

else:
    print("Please enter the value again")


